# Gulp gulp-sass "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open"

Tags: linux, node.js, permissions, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a node.js v4.2.1 and gulp. I use gulp-sass.
After the first compilation i get css file with permissions.

```
ls -la
-r--rw-r-- 1 user user 190K Oct 27 03:01 common.min.css
```

After subsequent compilations i get error.

```
stream.js:74
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/user/prj/sample/front/bin/css/common.min.css'
  at Error (native)
```

Why it is happens? Why is it sets this permissions? Previously, no such problems. Thank's.

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. Now  I use [gulp-rm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rm) for delete old common.min.css .

Answer (score 0):

check file permissions and ownsership and make sure you have the right to READ, WRITE & EXCUTE on this file ... or simply remove it and gulp will build a new file after transpiling. for more details on file permissions and if you are a linux user check this out.
[Introduction to Linux Permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions)